# How can I pass the value of a hidden text field to another php page?

Tags: php

I have a php page with the following:

```
echo "<form method='post'><input type='hidden' id='memberIdd' name='memberIdd' value=" . $memberId . "></form>";
```

Now I created another php page and want to grab the value of this hidden field and place it into another variable. How can I do this? I tried using this for my second php page:

```
$member = $_POST['memberIdd'];
```

But I just keep getting "undefined" for $member.

Thanks

Comment: Well you need a submit button in that form otherwise its not going to get posted to the server...

Comment: What does `var_dump($_POST)` display?

Comment: That's a hidden form field, but you've no submit button. The value won't appear in the second page unless you specify it as the form's action, and also submit the form. e.g. `echo "<form action='page2.php' method='post'><input type='hidden' id='memberIdd' name='memberIdd' value=" . $memberId . "><input type="submit" value="Go to page 2"></form>";`  Alternatively, you could store the value as a session variable.

Comment: @DarenChandisingh: I'd recommend posting your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form method='post' action='secondpage.php'>
```

http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.1

If you don't write the `action` then the posted data goes to the same page where you were.

And by the way, the variable `$memberId` (the one in your question) at the `firstpage.php` should be defined. In other case it will prompt error message.

Edit: It will better for you to use HTML codes out of PHP.

Answer (score 3):

I think your problem is that you did not set the right action in the form and you also should have a submit button. Thus, your form should look like:

```
echo '<form action="url-to-the-second-page.php" method="post">';
echo '<input type="hidden" id="memberIdd" name="memberIdd" value="' . $memberId . '">';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Even better, only use `<?php` for the PHP portions of the code, and echo straight HTML to the browser for the rest.

Comment: @mc10 You're right. This also improve performance (micro-optimization of course). BTW I usually like to use the same style of the OP for my answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

That's a hidden form field, but you've no submit button. The value won't appear in the second page unless you specify it as the form's action (i.e. where the form should be submitted to), and also submit the form. e.g.

```
echo "<form action='page2.php' method='post'>
      <input type='hidden' id='memberIdd' name='memberIdd' value=" . $memberId . ">
      <input type="submit" value="Go to page 2">
      </form>";
```

Alternatively, you could store the value as a session variable.